# Possibly questionable normalize function

Tags: directx

I've been using a vector class that has a normalize function as thus.

```
       float length = Length();
        if (!MathUtil.IsZero(length))
        {
            float inv = 1.0f / length;
            X *= inv;
            Y *= inv;
            Z *= inv;
        }
```

What I have found is, that in some situations, it seems to be producing a unit vector which isn't quite a unit vector.  Knowing that floating point is an approximation to a degree, in some cases where I am using this normalised vectors in a dot product and getting a dot value > 1.  Which is bad as in a Acos situation, it produces a NaN.

As the dot is used for camera rotation, it does produce a rotation nervous tick.

What I finally did was rewrite the code thus:

```
            float length = a_vector.Length();
        if (!MathUtil.IsZero(length))
        {
            a_vector.X /= length;
            a_vector.Y /= length;
            a_vector.Z /= length;
        }
```

which seems to of reduced this issue to almost 0.

At the moment, it's confirmation bias until otherwise told.  But my question is this, although definitely slower, is this a more accurate normalization?

Comment: Just to note, the initial code is not of my own doing.  Just trying to confirm that I am interpreting the what is happening correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on the inputs as to what the specific source of error is in your particular use case, as well as the optimization settings. As always, the seminal article on this is [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), and you should review the many very-useful floating-point articles on [this blog](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/).

Note that length should always be positive, and it's pretty always more robust to avoid equals tests with floating-point:

```
   float length = Length();
   if (length > 0)
   {
   ...
   }
```

In [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath), I provide two forms of normalization so that users of the math library can choose the tradeoff depending on the specific cases:

- `XMVector3NormalizeEst` does what your first function does: performs the reciprocal and then multiplies.
- `XMVector3Normalize` does what your second function does: performs a divide.

Comment: Cheers, yes, its what I suspected in terms of floating point.  Dividing each individual member indeed improves the accuracy, but there is still an edge case.  But for my purposes, I can live with it.  The Length test though I will use as yes, its a more accurate representation.  Testing for 0.0f in float is indeed frought with danger.